# How to get file history using git log since tag?

Tags: git

I looked at other answers on SO and identified that following command works, but does not honors the tag name in query

```
git log -p myReleaseTag ProductCatalog.java
```

This gives me all the changes in `patch` since the file was ever created.

How do I tell `git` to start from my tag `myReleaseTag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you're telling `log` to show all changes reachable from `myReleaseTag` (where "reachable from" means, more or less, "in the history of").

You could instead say

```
git log -p myReleaseTag..HEAD ProductCatalog.java
```

(or, slightly better practice:

```
git log -p myReleaseTag..HEAD -- ProductCatalog.java
```

as this will occasionally eliminate ambiguity in the command)

That would mean "all changes reachable from HEAD but *not* reachable from myReleaseTag".  If you want to include the changes from the commit market by `myReleaseTag`, then you could say

```
git log -p myReleaseTag^..HEAD -- ProductCatalog.java
```

(though that's only 100% straightforward if `myReleaseTag` isn't marking a merge).

More generally, the argument that's controlling what to show is a revision range; there are several options for notation to specify such a range.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

**UPDATE** - One more example

Another way to interpret what you asked would be if you want *every* change that *isn't* included in the release, regardless of what branch(es) can reach that change.  Then you could use

```
git log -p --all ^myReleaseTag -- ProductCatalog.java
```

and a change will be shown as long as it *isn't* present as of the release tag, and *is* reachable from some ref (tag, branch, ...)

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your help